# background transparent in separate window which has counter-tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-class

I wanted to have a countdown over my frame,but in order to create counter,I have to use Text or Label or other widgets which have background,but I needed to display only numbers over my frame,so I thought of creating the another window over the present frame and I tried using Toplevel() and grab_set and destroy the frame after few seconds.But I am facing difficulty in calling the countdown() and writing definition.
I just want the countdown numbers to display over my frame and those numbers should have transparent background.
I am stuck in calling countdown() and defining countdown according to new frame top.here in my code I am trying to display the number over canvas

```
class ExampleApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=2085, height=1080, bg='#020A2E')
        self.canvas.pack()
        top = Toplevel(self)
        top.grab_set()
        top.label = Label(self, text="", font='Arial 90 bold', fg='red',bg='black')
        top.label.place(x=100,y=100)
        top.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "black")
        top.remaining = 1
        self.countdown(3)
        top.grab_release()

    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.label.configure(text="")
            self.label.destroy()
        else:
            self.top.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `self.canvas.create_text(...)` to show the countdown on the main window?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution can be achieved once it is known how/when the countdown is called. But here is a version which works based on your code:

```
class TopWin(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.title('Window 2')
        self.geometry()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=150, height=150, bg='#020A2E')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.grab_set()
        self.label = Label(self.canvas, font='Arial 90 bold', fg='red',bg='black')
        self.label.place(x=5,y=5)
        self.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "black")
        self.remaining = 1
        self.countdown(3)
        self.grab_release()
        
    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            self.remaining = remaining

        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.label.configure(text="")
            self.destroy()
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining)
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            self.after(1000, self.countdown)
           
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Window 1')
        self.master.geometry('500x500')
        self.label = Label(self.master)
        self.label.pack()
        self.topWin = TopWin()
        
      
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.topWin.countdown(15)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for answering,but in your code you are creating two windows but the countdown is getting displayed in the first window,whereas I want it over 2nd window and this 2nd window needs to be completely Transparent as it should display only numbers.

Comment: I have just edited my answer. Try this version. But from the beginning the countdown was displaying in the second window. I added the titles for both windows. So it is easier for you now to recognize. In your code, you forgot to assign the self.canvas to the label once you defined it. I corrected it now. The place of the label you can set to x=0 and y=0 as well if you want.

Comment: **One more advice:** You can get rid of the black background when the countdown turns from two digits to one digit (10 to 9) by setting the number to have two digits like (09 08 ..etc). What you need to do is to replace %d in label.configure with %02d. Good luck